# SSIS Execute SQL Task - Deal with null values

Tags: sql-server, ssis, null

I am executing an SQL task with the following query:

```
"SELECT ISNULL(SUM(" + @[User::Amount] + "), 0) AS AMT FROM " + @[User::InTable]
```

Which comes from an SQLStatementSource expression.
Even though I use `ISNULL` for the result, I keep getting error when the `sum(amount)` is `NULL`. If there is an amount on the table, the result is correct and my flow is finished correctly.
What can I do to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: change is null to inside sum - SUM(ISNULL(Amount, 0)); I would prefer to use COALESCE instead of ISNULL

Comment: It still does not work - thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: If it does not have a record or has a record with a NULL amount there is the following error: [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "Amount": "Input string was not in a correct format.". If the table has at least one record with a valid amount, the result set is correct.

Comment: i Think the problem is that `@[User::Amount]` is null or somthing similiar. You need try before this sql task when assigning value to variable try to catch it and assign 0 if there no data in table.... :)

Comment: Thank you Justin that was it! Thanks!